# Can not get the required value using sql query in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I had one issue with my sql query. I am unable to get the proper data using **PHP** and **Mysql**. I am explaining my query below:

```
$todayDayId = date('N');
if($todayDayId > (int)$day_id) {
    $diff = (7-$todayDayId) +(int)$day_id;
}
else {
    $diff = (int)$day_id - $todayDayId;
}
$wantedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$diff.' day'));

$sql=" 
    select 
        c.cat_id,c.cat_name,c.special,s.subcat_id,s.subcat_name,s.status,s.order_no as order1,c.order_no as ord2, s.cat_id as scatid,b.status,sl.day_id,sl.date_from,sl.date_to 
    from db_category as c 
        inner join db_subcategory as s on s.cat_id=c.cat_id 
        inner join db_restaurant_detail as r on s.subcat_id= r.subcat_id 
        inner join db_restaurant_basic as b on r.member_id=b.member_id inner join db_special_images as sl on r.day_id=sl.day_id 
    where 
        r.day_id='3' 
        and c.special='2' 
        and r.city='1' 
        and (
            ((sl.date_from IS NULL or sl.date_from='') and (sl.date_to IS NULL or sl.date_to='')) 
            or (sl.date_from <='2016-12-07' and sl.date_to >= '2016-12-07' )
        ) 
        and b.status=1 
        and s.status=1 
    group by s.subcat_id 
    order by cast(ord2 as unsigned), scatid, cast(order1 as unsigned) asc"

$sqlqry = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlqry)) {                          
    $data[]=array("subcat_id"=>$row['subcat_id'],"subcat_name"=>$row['subcat_name']);
}
```

The above giving the below output.

```
[{"subcat_id":"4","subcat_name":"WHISKY"},
 {"subcat_id":"60","subcat_name":"SCOTCH"}, 
 {"subcat_id":"63","subcat_name":"RUM"}, 
 {"subcat_id":"56","subcat_name":"BEER"}]
```

But here my problem is for `{"subcat_id":"63","subcat_name":"RUM"}` `sl.date_from=2016-11-23 and sl.date_to=2016-11-30` but for `wantedDate=2016-12-07` the `RUM` is coming which should not come. Here I need if `sl.date_from='' and sl.date_to=''` then it can come but if any date is present then it will check. The wanted date should lie in between the given database date.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "for wantedDate=2016-12-07 the RUM is coming" . `$wantedDate` is not used anywhere in your SQL query, so it will have no effect on the result.

Comment: Something is not right here. If you get that record then all conditions in your SQL are being met. That means that either date_from and date_to are NULL (or empty strings) or they are before and after 2016-12-07. If they really were 2016-11-23 and 2016-11-30 the record would not be in the output. If it is then the dates are not right or a malformed joining of the tables leads to confusing results. I'd try getting a list without all the conditionals and filter just the subcat_id you have problems with, then check all the data related (dates).

Comment: You have a major issue with your SQL due to the way you have used GROUP BY. You are grouping by s.subcat_id, but there appear to be potentially multiple restaurants for each sub category (and I presume multiple images for each restaurant). While older versions of MySQL will not error by default in this situation (newer versions will), the values brought back are not defined. Hence which restaurant the value of b.status comes from is not defined, similarly which values of  special image.